# Backup app data without root and no micro USB port

Tags: backup, 4.2-jelly-bean

How can I backup an app's data (i.e. Angry Birds scores and achievements) on my Nexus 7, running Android 4.2.2? My tablet is not rooted and my micro USB port is damaged, disallowing me to connect to the computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your goal? Protect yourself from a factory reset? Move data to a new device?

Comment: Have a functioning BlueTooth?

Comment: I have a functioning Bluetooth

Comment: I am getting a new phone so I would like to transfer app data to the new device

Answer (score 1):

Probably Koush's [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup.license) [which used to be Carbon previously] might be of help for you.

> Helium does NOT require root.
>
> All Android users can use Helium to backup and sync Android
>   applications.
>
> Helium lets you backup your apps and data to your SD card or cloud
>   storage [Dropbox, Box, Google Drive].
>
> Android to Android app sync [With Helium, you can sync app data from
>   your other Android devices -- even if they are not on the same
>   network].

I am not sure if you have to connect your device to usb if you want to sync to cloud though. I have not used this feature as of yet.

Comment: Helium was my first thought too, but it won't work in this situation, because it has to be activated from the desktop application, which requires the USB to be hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult situation, but Google might come to your rescue. In 4.1.1 (on an AT&T SGS3, at least), in the `Settings` app, there are `Backup and reset` settings (in the `Personal` group):

[image: Screen shot of Backup and reset settings]

Now, despite the checkmarks, I've never actually used this feature, and there are a number of questions I can't answer (and I don't have the time at the moment to investigate):

- How often does it back up?
- Can it be used to restore to a different device?
- How can you know that any given app is backed up?
- Where are the backups stored on Google's servers / can a user access the backups in Drive?

You might need to experiment, or do some googleing. I just wanted to get at least this much up here so you can start.

Comment: I have a functioning Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Backup via SSH, FTP, SMB, WebDAV, Dropbox, Google Drive.... all via [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm).

I use it to transfer files back and forth and it works a delicious treat. I highly recommend this application.